# Facebook Like Button doesn't work in the server

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm using the [facebook plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) to create a Like button and it works locally but when I put it on my site, the plugin does not appear.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Seralto/UWQhn/

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fsergiotoledo.com.br%2F&amp;width=400&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=true&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:400px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Console log? any errors?

Comment: It does not display any error, just does not show the buttons as you can see in jsfiddle.

Comment: _"just does not show the buttons as you can see in jsfiddle."_, it works fine with Me

Comment: Very strange, I tested in other PC and they works too.
I don't know what happens in mine :(
But thanks anyway :)

Comment: I found the problem, my antivirus Avast was blocking the plugin :p